# Drawing an image to html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw an image to the html5 canvas, but can't quite remember exactly how it's done.

I have the following html document:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Understanding Business</title>

<section hidden>
<img id = "startButton" src = "startButton.png" alt = "Start Button" height = "40" width = "50" href = "javascript:drawFirstGameElements();">
</section>
</head>

<body onLoad = "drawStartButton()">
<h1>Understanding Business</h1>
<canvas id ="gameCanvas" width = "1000" height= "500" style = "border:1px solid #000000;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas.</canvas>

<script type = "text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ 
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var context = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
//gameCanvas.addEventListener('onclick', clickReporter, false);
gameCanvas.addEventListener('mouseMove', function(event){
    var mousePosition = getMouseCoords(gameCanvas, event);

});
/* Add some global variables */
var image = new Image();
var imageSource;
var imageX;
var imageY;


function drawStartButton(){
/*image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(image, 500, 250);
};
image.src = "startButton.png"; */
var startButtonImg = document.getElementById("startButton");
context.drawImage(startButtonImg, 500, 250);
}

function drawFirstGameElements(){
drawDescriptionBox1;
}
function drawDescriptionBox1(){
context.moveTo(100, 400);
context.lineTo(150, 400);
context.lineTo(150, 450);
context.lineTo(100, 450);
context.lineTo(100, 400);
context.moveTo(110, 425);
context.strokeText("Asset");
}

//Function to get mouse coordinates on canvas
function getMouseCoords(gameCanvas, event){
var rect = gameCanvas.getBoundingClientRect(), root = document.documentElement;

//return mouse position
var mouseX = event.clientX - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
var mouseY = event.clientY - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
return{
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY
};
}
}
```

For some reason, when I view the page in the browser, although the canvas is displayed, the "start button image" is not displayed on the canvas. It's been a while since I last used the HTML5 canvas, and I can't quite figure out what it is I'm doing wrong... Can someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,

**Edit**

Code updated to reflect changes as suggested, but I'm still having the same problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: recommend close for "too localised" since the error is a mere typo and nothing to do with the content of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your code :

```
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var context = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
//gameCanvas.addEventListener('onclick', clickReporter, false);
gameCanvas.addEventListener('mouseMove', function(event){
    var mousePosition = getMouseCoords(gameCanvas, event);

}); // HERE ADD );

/* Add some global variables */
var image = new Image();
var imageSource;
var imageX;
var imageY;
 //HERE DELETE THE }
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RqbPn/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've made the suggested changes, and saved the file, but when I reload the page in the browser, I still just get a blank canvas...

Comment: Delete the 
<body onLoad = "drawStartButton()"> and the function drawStartButton too, as I did in the fiddle. 
It might be called before the window.onload function so the canvas doesn't exist when you try to draw onto it